# Mod Rewrite - Additional Query String After Already Rewriting One Query String

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Appreciate the help in advance because I absolutely hate mod_rewrite and can't get my head around it!

I currently have a rule in my .htaccess that converts two parameters in a query string to a pretty URL.

```
RewriteRule ^projects/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ single-project.php?id=$1&section=$2 [L]
```

For example, this converts the URL **/single-project.php?id=5&section=documents** into **/projects/5/documents/**

What I want to do is have an additional query string (through a new rule) that would convert **/projects/5/documents/?subfolder=PDFs** into **/projects/5/documents/PDFs/**

A few caveats:

- This additional query string may not always be there
- This query string would only need to work if the URL is **/projects/[ANY_ID]/documents/**

I hope this makes sense and that you can help!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following rules in your .htaccess file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing URLs. Have added comments inside rule file for understanding.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Op's already present rules, added 1 more flag in it QSA.
RewriteRule ^projects/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ single-project.php?id=$1&section=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
##Newly added Rule to perform internal rewrite for project id here.
RewriteRule ^(projects)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ $1/$2/$3/?subfolder=$4 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: That's sorted it, I think. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DanielKilburn, your welcome, cheers and happy learning.